# Shopify Remix App: Open chat window on cart change

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, remix.run

I'm creating an Remix Shopify App using Shopify CLI.

I want to open a "dialog window" when the user creates or changes the cart.

At the moment I am using a "theme app extension" to render a window in the bottom right corner. I can open it by clicking it, but I would like it to open automatically when a user adds a product to the cart.

All I could do up to now is to send the cart change events to an external endpoint using the webhooks "cart create/change". But I need the reaction in the frontend.

I'm new to Remix so I don't know if Remix can do something like re-routing a webhook payload to a frontend handler function in a theme app extension(?) or if this behavior should be achieved in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

As you well know, every theme comes with a bunch of custom events now. One common event is the "cart:updated" variation. You would want to hook your theme app extension into that, so that you avoid any obscure and/or difficult messaging. No matter how great these extension from Shopify are though, it does remain tricky to hook into those events that are essentially someone's interpretation. Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I didn't know about those at all. The Shopify documentation is massive. Can you please share a link to somewhere I should look into those events, perhaps that one in particular? Thanks again

Comment: Look into your theme JS. Clearly you want to hook into that and those events!